# Bind combobox to sharepoint list

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online

This code shows how to use a combobox in a Sharepoint online webpart using react.  The sample data is hard coded.  How can I bind the combo box to a Sharepoint list?

````
```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ComboBox, Fabric, IComboBoxOption, mergeStyles, 
SelectableOptionMenuItemType, Toggle } from 'office-ui-fabric- 
react/lib/index';

const INITIAL_OPTIONS: IComboBoxOption[] = [
 { key: 'Header1', text: 'First heading', itemType: 
SelectableOptionMenuItemType.Header },
 { key: 'A', text: 'Option A' },
{ key: 'B', text: 'Option B' },
{ key: 'C', text: 'Option C' },
{ key: 'D', text: 'Option D' },
{ key: 'divider', text: '-', 
itemType: SelectableOptionMenuItemType.Divider },
{ key: 'Header2', text: 'Second heading', itemType: 
SelectableOptionMenuItemType.Header },
 { key: 'E', text: 'Option E' },
 { key: 'F', text: 'Option F', disabled: true },
 { key: 'G', text: 'Option G' },
 { key: 'H', text: 'Option H' },
 { key: 'I', text: 'Option I' },
 { key: 'J', text: 'Option J' }
  ];

  const wrapperClassName = mergeStyles({
  display: 'flex',
  selectors: {
  '& > *': { marginRight: '20px' },
  '& .ms-ComboBox': { maxWidth: '300px' }
  }
  });

  export interface IComboBoxTogglesExampleState {
  autoComplete: boolean;
  allowFreeform: boolean;
 }

 // tslint:disable:jsx-no-lambda
 export class ComboBoxTogglesExample extends React.Component<{}, 
 IComboBoxTogglesExampleState> {
 public state: IComboBoxTogglesExampleState = {
 autoComplete: false,
 allowFreeform: true
 };

public render(): JSX.Element {
const state = this.state;
return (
  <Fabric className={wrapperClassName}>
    <ComboBox
      label="ComboBox with toggleable freeform/auto-complete"
      key={'' + state.autoComplete + state.allowFreeform /*key causes re- 
    render when toggles change*/}
      allowFreeform={state.allowFreeform}
      autoComplete={state.autoComplete ? 'on' : 'off'}
      options={INITIAL_OPTIONS}
    />
    <Toggle
      label="Allow freeform"
      checked={state.allowFreeform}
      onChange={(ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, checked?: boolean) => 
   {
        this.setState({ allowFreeform: !!checked });
      }}
    />
    <Toggle
      label="Auto-complete"
      checked={state.autoComplete}
      onChange={(ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, checked?: boolean) => 
  {
        this.setState({ autoComplete: !!checked });
      }}
    />
  </Fabric>
  );
  }
}
```
````

This is for a Sharepoint Online webpart using the React Framework.

I have a list of 60 cost centers and I want them to appear in a combo box with autocomplete switched on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample demo(many test scenarios, just checking the logic you need):

```
export interface IListItem{
  Id: number;
  Title: string;
  Body : {
           Body_p1: string;
           Body_p2: string;
  };
}

export interface IReactExState{
  controlName:string,
  ControlValue:string,
  windowsID:number,
  showPanel:boolean,
  items: IListItem[],
  Options:IComboBoxOption[],
  selectionDetails: {},
  showModal: boolean,
  autoComplete: boolean,
  allowFreeform: boolean
}

export default class OfficeFabric extends React.Component<IOfficeFabricProps, IReactExState> {

  private _selection: Selection;
  private _allItems: IListItem[];
  private _columns: IColumn[];

  public constructor(props: IOfficeFabricProps,state: IReactExState){ 
    super(props); 
    this._selection = new Selection({
      onSelectionChanged: () => this.setState({ selectionDetails: this._getSelectionDetails() })
    });
    this._allItems = [
      {
        Id   : 0,
        Title : "test0",
        Body : {
                 Body_p1: "test0_p1",
                 Body_p2: "test0_p2"
               },
       },
       {
        Id  : 1,
        Title : "test1",
        Body : {
                 Body_p1: "test1_p1",
                 Body_p2: "test1_p2"
               }
       }
     ];
    this._columns = [
      { key: 'Id', name: 'Id', fieldName: 'Id', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
      { key: 'Title', name: 'Title', fieldName: 'Title', minWidth: 200, maxWidth: 400, isResizable: true },
      { key: 'Body', name: 'Body', minWidth: 200, maxWidth: 400, isResizable: true,onRender: (item) => (
        <div>          
         {item.Body.Body_p1}
          </div>) },
  ];
    this.state = { 
      controlName:"",
      ControlValue:"",
      windowsID:123.4,
      showPanel:false,
      items:this._allItems,
      Options:[],
      selectionDetails: this._getSelectionDetails() ,
      showModal:false,
      autoComplete: false,
      allowFreeform: true
    }; 
  }

  private _showModal = (): void => {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  };

  private _closeModal = (): void => {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  };

  private _getSelectionDetails(): string {
    const selectionCount = this._selection.getSelectedCount();

    switch (selectionCount) {
      case 0:
        return 'No items selected';
      case 1:
        return '1 item selected: ' + (this._selection.getSelection()[0] as IListItem).Title;
      default:
        return `${selectionCount} items selected`;
    }
  }

  private _onItemInvoked = (item: IListItem): void => {
    alert(`Item invoked: ${item.Title}`);
  };

  private _showPanel = () => {
    this.setState({ showPanel: true });
  };

  private _hidePanel = () => {
    this.setState({ showPanel: false });
  };
  private _Save = () => {
    //to do save logic
    this.setState({ showPanel: false });
    alert('save clicked');
  };
  private _onRenderFooterContent = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <PrimaryButton onClick={this._hidePanel} style={{ marginRight: '8px' }}>
          Save
        </PrimaryButton>
        <DefaultButton onClick={this._showPanel}>Cancel</DefaultButton>
      </div>
    );
  };

  public componentDidMount(){    
    var reactHandler = this;    
    this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?select=ID,Title`,
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1) .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
      response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {
        let tempOptions:IComboBoxOption[]=[];
        responseJSON.value.forEach(element => {
          tempOptions.push({key:element.ID,text:element.Title})
        });
        reactHandler.setState({
          Options: tempOptions
        });
      });  
    }); 
  }
  // private _onJobTitReportToChange = (ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, newValue?: string) => {
  //   this.props.onJobTitleReportToChange(newValue);
  // }

  public handleObjectWithMultipleFields  = (ev, newText: string): void => {
    const target = ev.target;
    const value = newText; 
    var _ControlName=target.name;

    this.setState({
      controlName: _ControlName,
      ControlValue:value
    })
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IOfficeFabricProps> {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.officeFabric }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
              <p className={ styles.subTitle }>Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
              <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>

              <ComboBox
              label="ComboBox with toggleable freeform/auto-complete"
              key={'' + this.state.autoComplete + this.state.allowFreeform /*key causes re- 
            render when toggles change*/}
              allowFreeform={this.state.allowFreeform}
              autoComplete={this.state.autoComplete ? 'on' : 'off'}
              options={this.state.Options}
            />
              <TextField name="txtA" value={this.state.windowsID.toString()}
           onChange={this.handleObjectWithMultipleFields}/>

              <TextField name="txtB"
           onChange={this.handleObjectWithMultipleFields}/>
              <div>
        <DefaultButton secondaryText="Opens the Sample Panel" onClick={this._showPanel} text="Open Panel" />
        <Panel
          isOpen={this.state.showPanel}
          type={PanelType.smallFixedFar}
          onDismiss={this._hidePanel}
          headerText="Panel - Small, right-aligned, fixed, with footer"
          closeButtonAriaLabel="Close"
          onRenderFooterContent={this._onRenderFooterContent}
        >
          <DefaultButton className={styles.tablink} text="Button" />
          <ChoiceGroup
            options={[
              {
                key: 'A',
                text: 'Option A'
              },
              {
                key: 'B',
                text: 'Option B',
                checked: true
              },
              {
                key: 'C',
                text: 'Option C',
                disabled: true
              },
              {
                key: 'D',
                text: 'Option D',
                checked: true,
                disabled: true
              }
            ]}
            label="Pick one"
            required={true}
          />
        </Panel>

        <DefaultButton secondaryText="Opens the Sample Modal" onClick={this._showModal} text="Open Modal" />

      </div>
              <MarqueeSelection selection={this._selection}>
              <DetailsList
                items={this.state.items}
                columns={this._columns}
                setKey="set"
                layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.justified}
                selection={this._selection}
                selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
                ariaLabelForSelectionColumn="Toggle selection"
                ariaLabelForSelectAllCheckbox="Toggle selection for all items"
                checkButtonAriaLabel="Row checkbox"
                onItemInvoked={this._onItemInvoked}
              />
            </MarqueeSelection>
              <a href="https://aka.ms/spfx" className={ styles.button }>
                <span className={ styles.label }>Learn more</span>
              </a>
              <Icon iconName='Mail' />
              <br/>
              <Icon iconName='CirclePlus' />
              <br/>
              <Icon iconName='LocationDot' />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: My constructor is has its own prop and state eg for a people picker.  Given that I can't have multiple constructors, how do I implement this?  Does it need a separate ts or tsx file?  If so, how do I bring it in to my main control?

Comment: Can't you set state for people picker and combox(or others) together?

Comment: Would it be possible to add npm install statements and the import statements especially for IOfficeFabricProps. I installed npm office-ui-fabric-react and added a line import { IOfficeFabricProps } from '../IOfficeFabricProps';. It's saying that it can't find the interface. There are about 60 6 digit cost centres. Once the user types the first digit the list of 60 should be filtered to those cost centres starting with the digit entered. Once they type the second digit, the list should be filtered to those cost centres starting with the two digits entered.  Only one cost centre can be chosen.

Comment: The webpart is a form that contains various fields eg the person's name and line manager.  When the user submits the form the results go into another Sharepoint list.  The selected cost centre will also go into this Sharepoint list.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this.

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("ChartOfAccounts").items.getAll().then((result: any)=>{
  for(let i: number = 0; i< result.length; i++) {
    const b: SPData = result[i];
    const c: IComboBoxOption={key:b.Column1, text: b.CostCentreInfo};
    INITIAL_OPTIONS.push(c);
}
```